# WPF Calendar Control holding on to the Mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

So I dropped the standard WPF `Calendar` control on the MainWindow.xaml in a brand new WPF App in VS2010.  If I click on a day in the calendar and then try to click the Close button for the app, I have to click twice on the close button before it accepts the click.  It's acting as if the `Calendar` hasn't released the Mouse to interact with the rest of the application.

I've changed `Focusable` to false, with no change in effect, and I've tried overriding the `PreviewOnMouseUp` and calling `ReleaseMouseCapture()` to no avail.  I've done the same thing with `MouseLeave` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` with the same result.  Given that none of those things are working I suspect I'm barking up the wrong tree.  Google has turned up nothing of note, though perhaps my GoogleFu is not up to snuff today.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can change this behavior by subscribing to the calendar's PreviewMouseUp event with a handler like this:

```
private void Calendar_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.Captured is CalendarItem)
    {
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should really be marked as the answer.  The accepted answer tells you why it happens, this one tells you how to stop it from happening.

Answer (score 2):

The calendar control is hosted in a popup, and captures the mouse.  When you click somewhere else the first time, the capture sends the click to the popup, which, realizing that you've clicked outside of itself, closes.  The click therefore does not go to the button.

You can see the same effect when using a ComboBox.  Drop it down, then click on a button.  It won't click the button.

Unfortunately, it's unlikely you can do anything to alter this behavior.

**Edit**: More recent versions of .NET make a solution possible.  See Eren's answer.

Comment: I don't see anything about a popup in the calendar class hierarchy. Calendar->Control->etc...->Object

Comment: @Ritch Melton: It still can use arbitrary controls in its `Template`, a ComboBox does not inherit from those classes either but also uses a Popup internally.

Comment: If you want to see for yourself, use Peter Blois' snoop utility to watch where the mouse clicks get lost.

Comment: Ritch Melton ran snoop, and its output proves my point -- the CalendarDayButton grabs the first click. Typically, the Popup is added to the visual tree of the enclosing control, and the mouse is captured to the enclosing control. This is how the calendar, combobox, and date/time picker controls work.

Comment: Interesting, and understandable given that the way the calendar control has been created makes it look like it's supposed to be used as part of a DateTimePicker control.  If you're using it in a more "static" type display scenario this behavior becomes rather annoying.  Regardless, I appreciate the info.

Comment: Yes, and I mostly failed, and broke the control too.

Comment: This should not be marked as the accepted answer. Eren's answer below has by far the most votes and gives a solution to the problem so the OP should really accept it as the answer.

Comment: Hi @The Lonely Coder, agreed.  Looks like newer versions of .NET allow you to disable the behavior nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basis of the code I use to work around both the mouse capture issue and the lack of Click events from child controls. It can probably be simplified further to make the calendar control more directly accessible, but I personally tend to add it into the UserControl.

```
class FixedCalendar : UserControl
{
    public FixedCalendar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);
        if (Mouse.Captured is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarItem)
        {
            Mouse.Capture(null);

            var element = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
                element.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        }
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="FixedCalendar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Calendar x:Name="Calendar" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Feel free to edit to make more general - I've quite literally cut the mostly relevant bits out of my current codebase and didn't want to edit too much in case I broke it.

Answer (score 1):

This code must help

```
Calendar.PreviewMouseUp += (o, e) =>
{
    if (!e.OriginalSource.Equals(Calendar))
    {
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
};
```

Comment: Not only this not work, it also introduces an effect that clicking in some parts of the calendar closes parent popup.