# How to avoid two click to select a row in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a main control that use two user controls. In the first one I have a custom calendar and in the second one a user control with a datagrid that shows information about the selected day.

I have notice that when I select a day in the calendar, if I want to select a row in the datagrid, I need two clicks. I guess that once it is to set the focus in the user control of the datagrid, but it doesn't select the row, so I need a second click to select the row.

So I would like to know if there are any way to select the row in the datagrid directly, with only one click.

---

#### Solved

I have solved the problem with the attached property solution given in this question:

[Have to click away twice from Calendar in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352961/have-to-click-away-twice-from-calendar-in-wpf)

Comment: did your datagird populates when you click on calendar?

Comment: Yes, when I click on the calendar, the datagrid is populated with the events of the day.

Comment: soo which row you want to select?

Comment: Any of them. I want that when I select a day, populate the datagrid, and later, select one of the events of the day to edit them. All works fine, the unique problem is that I need to click twice to select the row that I want to edit, and it is annoying to have to click twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have to click away twice from Calendar in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352961/have-to-click-away-twice-from-calendar-in-wpf)