# How can I prevent WPF Viewbox component from "stealing" focus from main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus

I currently have a little WPF window that contains only a Viewbox, which itself contains a Calendar component (so that resizing the window resizes the calendar to match). The XAML for this is:

```xml
<Window x:Class="CalendarTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CalendarTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="476.562">
    <Viewbox Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Calendar />
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

However, I'm finding some weird behaviour that I can't seem to find any other reference to from searching.

When I click to interact with the calendar (such as clicking on a date to select it, or change the month) and then try to interact with the window itself, I find that the focus seems to be "locked" on the Calendar or the Viewbox.

Clicking on minimize/maximize/close doesn't do anything but bring focus back to the window, at which point I can click those buttons and they function normally. While the focus is locked, hovering the bottom-right corner also doesn't display the typical "resize" cursor, until I click outside of the Calendar. Clicking on the Calendar again will lock the focus again.

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent this from happening?

I've tried setting this property on both the Viewbox and the Calendar but it doesn't prevent it from happening.
`Focusable="False"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352961/have-to-click-away-twice-from-calendar-in-wpf -seems like similar problem :)

Comment: @Kaspar Thank you, the solution to that question seems to have resolved my issue. Can't believe that never came up in my search!